# Default Operation TimeOut and Open TimeOut of WsManConnectionInfo

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Can anyone tell me the default Operation Timeout and Open Timeout of WsManConnectionInfo Object?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspaceconnectioninfo.opentimeout(v=vs.85).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspaceconnectioninfo.operationtimeout(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Found!!

Operation timeout default value is 3 minutes

open timeout default value is 3 minutes

Also,
Cancel timeout default value is 1 min